# Can someone explain why a value gets incremented when "++" is used for comparison?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration, increment

This may already be a question out there, but with the lack of specific key terms, it's a bit hard to search for. Just looking for more insight on this topic.

Right now, I'm working in C++ and wondering why my value is replaced with an incremented value when I compare using "++".

So here, we print 14 times (numbers 1-14).

```
int i = 0, x = 0;
while (x < 30) {
    x++;
    if (13 < i++) break;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Here, we print 30 zeros.

```
int i = 0, x = 0;
while (x < 30) {
    x++;
    if (13 < i+1) break;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

And this just plain doesn't work. (I wanted to try because `i++` = `i=i+1`).

```
int i = 0, x = 0;
while (x < 30) {
    x++;
    if (13 < i=i+1) break;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: `++i` = `i = i + 1`, the comparison evaluates to: `if (13 < i); ... ; i = i + 1`

Comment: Order of operations is important here, you're missing some parentheses.

Comment: The third piece of code really isn't the core of my question.

Answer (score 3):

Expression `i++` has both a value and a side effect. The value is that of `i`, and the side effect is that `i` is incremented (after having taken its value as expression result).

Expression `i+1`, in contrast, does not have a side effect, it only has a value (which is the value of `i` plus `1`) but leaves the value of `i` as it is.

That's why.

Comment: Thank you! Using "side effect" to explain makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Bella: You're welcome. Maybe you can accept the answer (the green check) if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

> And this just plain doesn't work. (I wanted to try because i++ =
>   i=i+1).

The reason it doesn't work is because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in this expression:

```
 if (13 < i=i+1) break;
```

It is evaluated by compiler as

```
if ((13 < i)=(i+1)) break;
```

and assignment to bool fails. What you need is to add correct parentheses for it to work:

```
int i = 0, x = 0;
while (x < 30) {
    x++;
    if (13 < (i=i+1)) break;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/0NSNwU

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```